# Excel Formula Vlookup with Criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

All.

I have a basic vlookup to sheet1 below.  The catch here is that In Sheet 1 , each lookup value has 2 rows.  Column D will either say "Tiger" or be blank.  I only want the vlookup to bring in the "Tiger" Rows.  Is this possible to add criteria so that it only does a vlookup for rows that have Column D populated as "Tiger?"

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,'Sheet1'!B:M,12,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly, but would something like this work if the data is always consecutive?

`=IF(INDEX('Sheet 1'!B:M, MATCH(B3, 'Sheet 1'!B:M, 0), 12)="", INDEX('Sheet 1'!B:M, MATCH(B3, 'Sheet 1'!B:M, 0)+1, 12), INDEX('Sheet 1'!B:M, MATCH(B3, 'Sheet 1'!B:M, 0), 12))`

Note that it's considered best practice to give explicit ranges rather than full columns (i.e. $B$1:$M$999 instead of B:M).

Comment: Hopefully this explains a bit better but let's say I am looking up with a value of Flower.  Flower will have 2 rows in sheet 1.  Flower Row 1 will just have a blank value in column D.  Flower Row 2 will have the word Tiger in column D.  So if I do a generic vlookup it will take the first blank row every time, whereas in reality I need the second row with the actual value (rows with Tiger).

Comment: If the blank row and filled row are always consecutive, you can use the above edited formula

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are multiple ways of doing things in Excel.  If the result column you want is a number, I'd tend to use SUMPRODUCT. If you have any duplicate rows, though, that will add them up. Using INDEX/MATCH you can choose to just take the first one it finds. The image below has an example of each. If the result column isn't a number, then the SUMPRODUCT will give a #VALUE error.  Hopefully you can see how the example applies to your situation and adapt it. The formulas are what is in cells E2 and E4.

[image: Using SUMPRODUCT and INDEX/MATCH to query two columns]